# Unable to send bulk attachments using php mail

Tags: php, email, cakephp, cakephp-2.0, sendmail

I'm sening an email with bulk attachments using php mail function, the mail was sent without attachments where as on including attachments the mail wasn't sent, don't know why

I'm using cakephp "Default" email settings to send email, it internally calls the php native mail function to send the mail, check the [api](http://api.cakephp.org/2.3/source-class-MailTransport.html#51-72)

What's the reason behind it, should i need to change any configurations in my server

Thanks in advance

Comment: How do you expect anyone to reply if you do not post your code and the data you are working with? We are good, but we are not that good that we can magically guess that.

Comment: Also: what exactly do you mean by "was not sent"? What error do you get?

Comment: it doesn't return any errors, it's showing exception if mail not sent `if (!@mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers)) {throw new SocketException(__d('cake_dev', 'Could not send email.'));}`

Comment: Please take a look into your http servers error log file. That is where you will find the reason why the `mail()` function fails.

Comment: Also updating your CakePHP core may give you a more informative error message. **http://api.cakephp.org/2.4/source-class-MailTransport.html#66-82**

Comment: Thanks @ndm, I'll try your suggestion.

Comment: Got `null` value for `error_get_last` function, No detailed explanation of error message